# static or objects what's better in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have WCF method that looks something like this:

```
public GetRecordsResponse GetRecords(GetRecordsRequest request)
        {
            GetRecordsResponse response = new GetRecordsResponse();

                Util.GetRecords.VerifyMandatoryParameters(request);
                //make sure mandatory parameters have correct values.
                Util.GetRecords.SetDefaultValues(request);

                Util.GetRecords.SetDefaultResponseValues(request, response);

                DataReader.GetRecords.GetAllRecords(request, response);

            return response;
        }
```

Is it wrong that i have the entire DAL and many Helper methods as static classes and methods? If so, why?

Comment: Personally, we use several static methods in our **DAL** (Data Access Layer). Just be mindful that you aren't creating too much with your factories.

Comment: The main thing that jumps out at me is the naming.  If these are real names in your code, there's probably room for improvement.

Comment: Since you have to verify mandatory parameters which will differ for every RequestObject but will be specific to a RequestObject, i will suggest you to create private method withing the DAL class for that purpose. Also having entire DAL static will do no good (No unit testing?)

Comment: The only time I use `static` methods are for utilities. I find it just as simple to require a new instance to be created/used (which I find this is often amendable to injection/stubbing/testing/interfaces, which can be easily "given up" when using static methods).

Comment: Hope the GetRecordsRequest parameter that you are passing is thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a result of using Static method you can access instance variables like properties and fields this means you need to pass the request to every method.

If you used instances of GetRecords you could do somehting liek

```
   GetRecords gr = new gr();
   gr.Request = request;
   gr.VerifyMandatoryParameters();
   gr.SetDefaultValues();
   gr.SetDefaultResponseValues(response);
   gr.GetAllRecords();
```

Also if you implment a  fluent interfaces you could have written it like this.

```
   GetRecords gr = new gr();
   gr.SetRequest(request)
     .VerifyMandatoryParameters()
     .SetDefaultValues()
     .SetDefaultResponseValues(response)
     .GetAllRecords();
```

But there's nothing "wrong" with what you did

Comment: Thanks Conrad... could you elaborate on your first sentence please. How would i not have to pass the request to every method? You mean i would have ONE master GetRecords object that i would pass the request in which would call all the util methods as well as DAL methods?

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your update (+1). Forgive me for not jumping to give you the answer on this one. I want to let it "simmer" and see if any new thoughts come up.

Answer (score 1):

This is subjective matter, but I think that static methods are evil in general (except very few situations).

Here is a link to a talk discussing why this is a problem:
http://misko.hevery.com/2008/11/11/clean-code-talks-dependency-injection/

Although the speaker is talking about Java, but it is quite similar language, and static methods are being used almost the same way in both languages.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Yes.

I imagine that you are performing few to no unit tests against your code.  If you plan on adding any, at any point; a statically accessed DAL will cause you no end of grief (I am dealing this exact scenario right now).

Instead, you should be passing in, say a **DataAccessService** interface, that can be mocked for testing, and implemented pointing to your actual data store in production.

So, I would expect your code to look more like:

```
public GetRecordsResponse GetRecords(GetRecordsRequest request, DataAccessService dataAccess)
        {
            var response = new GetRecordsResponse();

            Util.GetRecords.VerifyMandatoryParameters(request);
            Util.GetRecords.SetDefaultValues(request);    
            Util.GetRecords.SetDefaultResponseValues(request, response);

            dataAccess.GetAllRecords(request, response);

            return response;
        }
```